# Going from a single 3TB disk to a 4-disk 6TB RAID10

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have a 3TB standalone disk (EXT4 in a 4-bay eSATA box) that I would like to integrate into a RAID10 array by adding 3 more 3TB disks.  I'm hoping to do this nondestructively, as it would take considerable time to migrate the data off and then migrate it back once the array has been built.

NOTE: The drive I want to RAID is not a boot volume - it's storage-only.  Not sure if that matters.

I've read instructions [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/convert-raid-1-system-into-raid-1-0-a-557471/) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/610538/convert-raid-1-to-raid-10-in-mdadm) about converting RAID1 to RAID10, and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/44574/can-i-create-a-soft-raid1-array-without-nuking-data) about creating the RAID1 from the original drive (create degraded, copy data, add original drive to array), but I'm wondering if I'm headed for any pitfalls if I try to stepping-stone my way from a single drive to RAID10.  Logically, I would think it'd be fine as long as I wait for the RAID1 to finish building and verify that it's good before I do the RAID10 expansion, but I'm not sure if there's a caveat I haven't considered yet.

Is it as simple as what I've read?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm hoping to do this nondestructively, as it would take considerable time to migrate the data off and then migrate it back once the array has been built.

I'm not sure what you mean. You have to migrate the data from your plain disk to your new array in any case. As [one of the answers](https://superuser.com/a/726063/252532) already suggested, you can create a RAID10 array with two missing drives and add them later after you finished migrating your data. This is easier than migrating from RAID1 or RAID0 to RAID10.

Remember that redundancy of RAID doesn't count as a backup. If you somehow mess up your array or corrupt data, then your data is lost or corrupted permanently. At least have another 6 TB volume as a backup if something goes wrong. (I was in a similar situation a few years ago, using Debian (stable), MDADM and EXT4, which I thought was fine, until I ran an MD5 check on some of the files and found several corruptions. After mounting the same array on the latest Ubuntu and checking again most files that had corruptions before were fine. You never know which bugs you might run into, therefore have an offline backup!)

You might want to look into the RAID capabilities of ZFS on Linux or btrfs, which solve issues and provide advanced features like partitioning/LVM, [silent data corruption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_corruption#Silent_data_corruption), snapshots, compressing content on the fly and so forth.